# pydev debugger: process 96437 is connectingエラーの原因が分からない

Tags: python

統計的声質変換をしようとしておりプログラムを実行したが、このようなデバッグエラーが出て困っています。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
pydev debugger: process 96437 is connecting
```

**ソースコード**

```
import numpy
import os
import struct
import sys

class STF:
    def __init__(self, filename = None):
        self.endian = '>'
        self.chunks = ['APSG', 'F0', 'SPEC']

    def loadfile(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as stf_file:
            self.load(stf_file)

    def load(self, stf_file):
        filesize = os.fstat(stf_file.fileno()).st_size

        while stf_file.tell() < filesize:
            chunk = stf_file.read(4)

            if chunk == 'STRT':
                if stf_file.read(2) == '\xff\xfe':
                    self.endian = '<'
                chunk_size, self.version, self.channel, self.frequency = struct.unpack(self.endian + 'IHHI', stf_file.read(12))
            else:
                chunk_size, = struct.unpack(self.endian + 'I', stf_file.read(4))

                if chunk == 'CHKL' or chunk == 'NXFL':
                    data = stf_file.read(chunk_size)
                    if chunk == 'CHKL':
                        self.chunks += [data[i: i + 4] for i in range(0, chunk_size, 4) if data[i: i + 4] not in self.chunks]
                else:
                    self.shift_length, frame_count, argument, self.bit_size, self.weight, data_size = struct.unpack(self.endian + 'dIIHdI', stf_file.read(30))
                    data = stf_file.read(data_size)

                    element = data_size / (self.bit_size / 8)
                    matrix = numpy.fromstring(data, count = element)

                    for c in self.chunks:
                        if chunk == c:
                            if element / frame_count == 1:
                                self.__dict__[c.strip()] = matrix
                            else:
                                self.__dict__[c.strip()] = matrix.reshape((frame_count, element / frame_count))
                            break

        for c in self.chunks:
            if c.strip() not in self.__dict__:
                self.__dict__[c.strip()] = None

    def savefile(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'wb') as stf_file:
            self.save(stf_file)

    def save(self, stf_file):
        stf_file.write('STRT')
        if self.endian == '>':
            stf_file.write('\xfe\xff')
        elif self.endian == '<':
            stf_file.write('\xff\xfe')
        stf_file.write(struct.pack(self.endian + 'IHHI', 8, self.version, self.channel, self.frequency))

        stf_file.write('CHKL')
        stf_file.write(struct.pack(self.endian + 'I', len(''.join(self.chunks))) + ''.join(self.chunks))

        for c in self.chunks:
            if self.__dict__[c.strip()] is None:
                continue

            matrix = self.__dict__[c.strip()]
            if len(matrix.shape) == 1:
                argument = 1
            else:
                argument = matrix.shape[1]
            data_size = matrix.shape[0] * argument * 8

            header = struct.pack(self.endian + 'dIIHdI', self.shift_length, matrix.shape[0], argument, self.bit_size, self.weight, data_size)
            stf_file.write(c + struct.pack(self.endian + 'I', len(header) + data_size) + header)

            for i in xrange(matrix.shape[0]):
                if argument == 1:
                    stf_file.write(struct.pack(self.endian + 'd', matrix[i]))
                else:
                    for j in xrange(matrix.shape[1]):
                        stf_file.write(struct.pack(self.endian + 'd', matrix[i, j]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('Usage: %s <stf_file>' % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit()

    stf = STF()
    stf.loadfile(sys.argv[1])
    print(stf.F0)
```

Comment: この記事 [pydev debugger is not connecting](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205967904) で質問は逆に未接続ですが、途中で接続での質問もあり、何かしたら直った発言もあるので参考になるかも。

Comment: デバッグモードで実行する必要がなければ通常モード(Run As)で実行する方が良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: たいへん初心者すぎる質問で申し訳ありませんが変数の確認の仕方も教えていただけませんか